# Como puedo hacer que mi p-multiSelect quede de forma responsiva?

Tags: angular, primeng

Estoy probando los componentes de primeng, pero al ocupar el multiSelect no se me adecuado de una forma correcta.

```html
 <!--MultiSelect-->
                    <h4>Grupo de producto</h4>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="{{anchoEntreCombobox.MD}}">
                        <p-multiSelect [style]="{'width': '500px'}" [options]="listadoProductos" [(ngModel)]="parametros.product" optionLabel="descripcion" defaultLabel="Producto" display="chip" (selectionChange)="changeProduct()"></p-multiSelect>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Variedad de producto</h4>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="{{anchoEntreCombobox.MD}}">
                        <p-multiSelect [style]="{'width':'500px'}" [options]="listadoProductos" [(ngModel)]="parametros.product" optionLabel="descripcion" defaultLabel="Variedad" display="chip"></p-multiSelect>
                    </div>
```

[image: Imagen]

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con estilos relativos al ancho de la vista o con media queries ejemplo

```
   <p-multiSelect
  [options]="cities"
  [style]="{ width: '80vw' }"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"
  defaultLabel="Select a City"
  optionLabel="name"
>
</p-multiSelect>
```

la otra idea es con media queries dependiendo de la resolución le acomodas el ancho, puedes colocar un max width o un min si lo requieres